# entity framework stored procedure result to domain model

Tags: c#, entity-framework, lambda

I'm going through old projects at work trying to make them faster. I'm currently looking at some web APIs. One API is running particularly slow the problem is in the data service it is calling. Specifically it is in a lambda method trying to map a stored procedure result to a domain model. A simple version of the code.

```
public IEnumerable<DomainModelResult> GetData()
{
    return this.EntityFrameworkDB.GetDataSproc().ToList()
           .Select(sprocResults=>sprocResults.ToDomainModelResult())
           .AsEnumerable();
}
```

This is a simplified version, but after profiling it I found the major hangup is in the lambda function. I am assuming this is because the EFContext is still open and some goofy entity framework stuff is happening.

Problem is I'm relatively new to Entity Framework(intern) and pretty ignorant to the inner workings of it. Could someone explain why this is so slow. I feel it should be very fast The DomainModelResult is a POCO and only setter methods are being used in ToDomainModelResult.

Edit:
I thought `ToList()` would do that but started to doubt myself because I couldn't think of another explanation. All the `ToDomainModelResult()` stuff is extremely simple. Something like.

```
public static DomainModelResult ToDomainModelResult(SprocResult source)
{
    return new DomainModeResult
    {
    FirstName = source.description,
    MiddleName = source._middlename,
    LastName = source.lastname,
    UserName = source.expr2,
    Address = source.uglyName
    };
}
```

Its just a bunch of simple setters, I think the model causing problems has 17 properties. The reason this is being done is because the project is old database first and the stored procedures have ugly names that aren't descriptive at all. Also so switching the stored procedures in dataservices is easy and doesn't break the rest of the project.

Edit:2 For some reason Using `ToArray` and breaking apart the linq statements makes the assignment from procedure result to domain model result extremely fast. Now the whole dataservice method is faster which is odd, I don't know where the rest of the time went.

This might be a more esoteric question than I originally thought. My question hasn't been answered but the problem is no longer there. Thanks to all the replied. I'm keeping this as unanswered for now.

Edit3: Please flag this question for removal I can't remove it. I found the problem but it is totally unrelated to my original question. I misunderstood the problem when I asked the question. The increase in speed I'm chalking up to compiler optimization and running code in the profiler. The real issues wasn't in my lambda but in a dynamic lambda called by entity framework when the context is closed or an object is accessed it was doing data validation. GetString, GetInt32, and ISDBNull were eating up the most time. So I'm assuming microsoft has optimized these methods and the only way to speed this up is possibly making some variable not nullable in the procedure. This question is misleading and so esoteric I don't think it belongs here and will just confuse people. Sorry.

Comment: As soon as you call ToList() the SQL query is executed and complete. If the problem is in the lambda, it probably has more to do with ToDomainModelResult() than anything with EF. Can you show the code of that method?

Answer (score 1):

You should split the code and check which one is taking time.

```
public IEnumerable<DomainModelResult> GetData()
{
    var lst = this.EntityFrameworkDB.GetDataSproc().ToList();
    return lst
           .Select(sprocResults=>sprocResults.ToDomainModelResult())
           .AsEnumerable();
}
```

I am pretty sure the GetDataSproc procedure is taking most of your time. You need to optimize the stored procedure code

**Update**
If possible, it is better to do more work on SQL side instead of retrieving 60,000 rows into your memory. Few possible solutions:

- If you need to display this information, do paging (top and skip)
- If you are doing any filtering or calculating or grouping anything after you retrieve rows in memory, do it in your stored proc
- .Net side, as you are returning `IEnumerable` you may able to use `yield` on your second part, depends on your architecture

Comment: I thought the stored procedure would be the one taking all the time as well, but using the .net profiler it says the stored procedure takes about a quarter second, and the lambda takes about 10.

Comment: I will split and check with a stopwatch anyway, but running the procedure on sql manager it seems to be pretty fast.

Comment: It is a lot of data I'm dealing with aggregate reports on people in colleges within a university. Even considering that is seems slow, but an average report would have about 40,000-60,000 rows.

Comment: I just did a few simple tests just using stopwatch, the procedure isn't as fast as the profiler said, but the lambda is still taking longer. It takes about 150% the time the procedure takes.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, breaking them apart helped troubleshooting but mainly through trial an error. I have no idea why it was slower, but using `ToArray` and breaking up the linq statements makes it faster. I just can't understand the .net magic in this case, regardless thanks you helped!